Cannot get sudo to work for a user on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
I have added user1 to sudoers group. This confirmed successful as follows:
user1 : user1 sudo

I believe the permissions are set correctly in visudo as follows:
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

I have logged in and out. I even rebooted the server. I get the following error when I execute:
sudo ls
*entered password*
Sorry, user user1 is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/ls' as root on server1.

I have read countless articles on sudo. I cannot see that I am doing anything wrong. Help appreciated.

If your details are accurate (as provided), you're behind on applying security & other fixes/upgrades to your system, as https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/02/22/ubuntu-22-04-4-lts-released/ shows the ISO release date of 22.04.4, but installed systems upgraded before that date. Your details may show you have other problems too, so I suggest checking your system details.

Thanks!! and now all updated to 22.04.4 LTS.  It also fixed my sudoers problem.

You added user1, but, your error message shows another user users1 ... If that is not a typo in your question, then the two users are different as it appears.

It's not clear what command you ran when you "confirmed successful as follows" but group memberships (despite showing the the output of the groups command for example) are not actually applied until the user starts a new login session - which likely happened as a side effect of your system update

@karel, ref your link, not sure how that is similar to my problem.  That person states, "I had set user1 to execute only sudo bash command and forgotten about it."

I update to 22.04.4 LTS. It also fixed my sudoers problem
